# Need to add a horizontal line to divide the rows in asp gridview

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, gridview

I have a requirement where I  need to create dynamic rows with controls and for that I have used gridview. The issue is I am unable to display a black horizontal line between rows.

Requirement:
[image]

My design:
[image]

css:

```
.alternateStyler {
margin-top:2px;  // just wanted to see if it works, did not work though.    
}
```

Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDelayIssueRisk" Width="98%" CssClass="labels" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
   Style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"
   OnSelectedIndexChanging="gvDelayIssueRisk_SelectedIndexChanging"
   OnRowDataBound="gvDelayIssueRisk_RowDataBound"
   AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alternateStyler">
   <Columns>
      <%--   <asp:BoundField DataField="noteid" HeaderText="ID" />--%>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type" ItemStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" FooterStyle-VerticalAlign ="Top">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblType" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Author") %>' Visible="false" />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlType" Width="98%" runat="server" CssClass="DropDownListStyle"></asp:DropDownList>
         </ItemTemplate>
         <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlType2" Width="98%" runat="server" CssClass="DropDownListStyle"></asp:DropDownList>
         </FooterTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Impact" ItemStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" FooterStyle-VerticalAlign ="Top">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblImpact" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Author") %>' Visible="false" />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlImpact" Width="98%" runat="server" CssClass="DropDownListStyle"></asp:DropDownList>
         </ItemTemplate>
         <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlImpact2" Width="98%" runat="server" CssClass="DropDownListStyle"></asp:DropDownList>
         </FooterTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DIR Description" ItemStyle-Width="20%" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" FooterStyle-VerticalAlign ="Top">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDIRDesc" Width="98%" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="100px" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("notes")%>'></asp:TextBox>
         </ItemTemplate>
         <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDIRDesc2" Width="98%" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="100px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         </FooterTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remediation Plan" ItemStyle-Width="20%" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" FooterStyle-VerticalAlign ="Top">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtRemPlan" Width="98%" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="100px" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("notes")%>'></asp:TextBox>
         </ItemTemplate>
         <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtRemPlan2" Width="98%" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="100px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         </FooterTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Owner" ItemStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" FooterStyle-VerticalAlign ="Top">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtOwner" Width="98%" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("notes")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtOwner2" Width="98%" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Due Date" ItemStyle-Width="8%" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" FooterStyle-VerticalAlign ="Top">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="dtDueDate" CssClass="Datetext" Width="98%" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DateAdded")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="dtDueDate2" CssClass="Datetext" Width="98%" runat="server">
                                                    </asp:TextBox>
                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Complete Date" ItemStyle-Width="8%" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" FooterStyle-VerticalAlign ="Top">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="dtCompleteDate" CssClass="Datetext" Width="98%" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DateAdded")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="dtCompleteDate2" CssClass="Datetext" Width="98%" runat="server">
                                                    </asp:TextBox>
                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField> 
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Notes" ItemStyle-Width="20%" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" FooterStyle-VerticalAlign ="Top">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDelayNotes" Width="98%" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="100px" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("notes")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDelayNotes2" Width="98%" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="100px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ItemStyle-CssClass` to each `TemplateField` in your grid i.e.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type" ItemStyle-CssClass="someClass"  ItemStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" FooterStyle-VerticalAlign ="Top">...
```

Definition of your `someClass` rule should like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.someClass
{
  border-bottom:solid 1px black;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Just added 
 padding-bottom:1em;
 padding-top:1em;
 and FooterStyle-CssClass="SomeClass" , that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Headername" ItemStyle-CssClass="Hrline" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Hrline"> </<asp:TemplateField>
```

and add following css in your page

```
   <style type="text/css">
    .Hrline{ border-bottom:solid 1px black;}
    </style>
```